# Is Keras Sequential fit the same as several train_on_batch calls?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Just confused as to the differences between keras.sequential `train_on_batch` and `fit`. Is the only difference that, with `train_on_batch`, you automatically pass over the data only once whereas with `fit` you specify this with the no. of `epochs`?

If I do `model.fit(x, y, epochs=5)` is this the same as 
`for i in range(5)
     model.train_on_batch(x, y)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I do `model.fit(x, y, epochs=5)` is this the same as
>   `for i in range(5)    model.train_on_batch(x, y)?`

Yes.

Your understanding is correct.

There are a few more bells and whistles to `.fit()` (we, can for example, artificially control the number of batches to consider an epoch rather than exhausting the whole dataset) but, fundamentally, you are correct.